# Creating a duplicate row function in PHP for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a function that duplicates a row based on what table, column and matching variable you pass into the function.  I basically insert a blank row and get the id of that row and then later on update it with the new information.  The problem I am running into is that sometimes the table has a unique key so I am getting a lot of Duplicate entry for key errors.

Before the row gets updated I check to see if it is a column that has a unique key and if so just to insert a blank basically, but this still isn't working.  Is there a way to have it generate a random value for this column just until the user changes it?

Here is my code for the duplicate function:

```
   public function duplicateRecord($table, $column, $record) {

        $dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$column} = '{$record}'";

        $describe_query = "DESCRIBE {$table}";
        $describe_result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$describe_query);

        $unique_arr = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($describe_result)) {

            if ($row['Key'] == 'PRI' || $row['Key'] == 'UNI') {

                $unique_arr[] = $row['Field'];

            }

        }

        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
        $original = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`{$column}`) VALUES (NULL)";
        mysqli_query($dbcon, $insert_query);
        $newid = mysqli_insert_id($dbcon);

        $update_query = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";
        foreach ($original as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != $column) {

                if (in_array($key,$unique_arr)) {

                    $update_query .= "{$key} = NULL, ";

                } else {

                    $update_query .= "{$key} = '{$value}', ";

                }

            }
        }

        $update_query = substr($update_query,0,strlen($update_query)-2);
        $update_query .= " WHERE {$column} = '{$newid}'";

        echo $update_query;

        mysqli_query($dbcon, $update_query);

        return $newid;

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can't you just set this column to empty string?

Comment: I've tried that, but unless the user goes in and updates the empty string to a value before duplicating again, it still throws an error. A value of `''` is still a unique value.

Comment: I see `if ($row['Key']` which tells me that you've a row called "Key", correct? If so, then you do know that "key" is MySQL reserved word and requires special attention if you're not already doing so. I guess "DESCRIBE" takes care of that.

Comment: Yes, if you look above, this is from the `DESCRIBE {$table}` query that basically gets the table schema, that's how I am checking if the row is a unique key or not.

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't entirely sure about it; I had to ask.

Answer (score 1):

So basically what I ended up doing was just using an md5 of the table name and the new id to generate a 10 character substring that I insert just as a filler, this way if the user duplicates the same row many times, there will always be a unique value inserted.

Although, if someone knows a more elegant solution, I'm always open to suggestions. :)

```
if (in_array($key,$unique_arr)) {

    $unique = md5($table.$newid);
    $unique = substr($unique,0,10);

    $update_query .= "{$key} = '{$unique}', ";

}
```

Comment: MD5 will produce the same hash if the table name is the same name. You might want to add something to it, like a UNIX timestamp, and `uniqid()`.

Comment: Yes, I could add the time, I concatenated the new product id as well, as that will also be unique, thanks!